# Exomedia video not playing

Tags: android, video

I try to change my video player
here github repos
https://github.com/brianwernick/ExoMedia

i use this lib
but video not playing

here my sample code

```
   <com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/video_view"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    app:useDefaultControls="true"
    app:useTextureViewBacking="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
```

java file

```
 private VideoView videoView;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);



    findViewById(R.id.video_view).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"edit",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            if (videoView.isPlaying()) {
                videoView.pause();
            }


            videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("https://archive.org/download/Popeye_forPresident/Popeye_forPresident_512kb.mp4"));

            videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                    videoView.start();

                }
            });
        }
    });
}
@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    //Starts the video playback as soon as it is ready
   videoView.start();
}
```

when i press on player only player display but video still not loaded
so plz help me

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me. Just need to change the VideoView import

**from**

```
import android.widget.VideoView;   //  WRONG :-(
```

**to**

```
import com.devbrackets.android.exomedia.ui.widget.VideoView;  // RIGHT :-)
```